# textarea change its height on each keypress

Tags: jquery, textarea

```js
$('#txstory').on('input', function () {
 $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id='txstory'></textarea>
```

why `txstory` change its height on each keypress?

It should happen only when a new row of text is there.

Answer (score 0):

'Height()' and 'scrollHeight()' are different.

height does not include padding.

scrollHeigth include padding, not border or margin.

---

add comment,

```
$('#txstory').on('input', function () {
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});
```

this code means

if input character in `$('#txstory')`, you change `$('#txstory')`'s height to `$('#txstory')`'s scrollHeight.

init `$('#txstory')`'s height is 30px and There is a padding of 2px up and down.

so height is 30, scrollHeight is 34.

To act the way you want,

```js
    $('#txstory').on('keydown keyup', function () {
     $(this).height(1).height( $(this).prop('scrollHeight')+12 );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='txstory' style='min-height:30px;'></textarea>
```

Comment: the question is - why is height of textarea changed on each keypress? padding border and margins are the same if content is `a` or `ab`

Comment: again - type `a` in my code snippet. the height will change. now continue to type and you'll see that height continue to change. `scrollheight` is the same regardles of `a` or `abc` is inside.